# Document Parent Name Lacks A Forward Slash

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am getting the following error when running the Firestore emulator locally and hitting it with the following URI:

```html
http://localhost:8025/v1/projects/my-project/databases/db/documents/cities/LA
```

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Document parent name \"projects/my-project/databases/db/documents/cities\" lacks \"/\" at index 56.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

I am using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument) API reference as a guide. Where am I going wrong in my project name construction?

Answer (score 4):

I am also running into this error, and the problem was you can't specify the document's `id` in the URL's path, you need to add `documentId` in the query of that URL.

So in your case, when creating a document with an id that the client specified, the correct URL is:
`http://localhost:8025/v1/projects/my-project/databases/db/documents/cities?documentId=LA`

Edit:
This was documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument

Comment: This is my issue, thanks.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you.  Is this documented anywhere you can share?

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore emulator provided by the Firebase CLI doesn't implement the REST API you're looking at.  That API is for the cloud-hosted database instance for your project.

What the emulator does support is [building your Android, iOS, web, and nodejs app locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite#which_firebase_features_and_platforms_are_supported).

Comment: hmm..I get the same error message even if I use the API explorer: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument, which tells me it's not an emulator problem

Comment: I think I might not have been clear.  The emulator doesn't expose a documented API endpoint.  It's meant for use with the client SDKs.  Please read the link from my answer.  The API you're trying to use is for cloud hosted Firestore instances only.

Comment: I thought I could do the same as with Datastore. I am able to hit the Datastore emulator using the Datastore REST API. Not sure why they didn't do the same for Firestore.

Comment: The Firebase emulator for firestore is not at all the same as any other emulator you might have used for datastore. I suggest sticking to the documentation and samples to understand how it works.

Comment: Well, it's inconsistent. There's a REST API for Firestore so they should have supplied it just like they did with Datastore. After all, they are selling Firestore as a replacement for Datastore. I will go back to Datastore.

Comment: I understand.  If you have feedback for the Firebase team, please file an issue with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support